# How to dust proof and waterproof garage concrete screed?

Tags: flooring, garage

I want to treat my single garage floor (15sqm) which is apparently made of soft concrete screed. It looks as being in good shape with no cracks and no signs of water coming but I just want to be sure I would block any future humidity.

The screed is has some small ridges on it as it was not polished and I exclude this step because it is very expensive, messy and labour intensive. I use the garage only for storage but I want to minimise humidity and dust in it.

I found two Sika solutions that should deal with the two issue dust proofing and waterproofing but i don’t know in which order I should lay them, or if I could just mix them and paint with the mix.

Common sense tells me that waterprofing would be last but I have to ask...

https://www.sealantsdirect.co.uk/sika-1-waterproofer-5l.html
https://www.sealantsdirect.co.uk/brands/sika/sikabond-pva-1l.htm
https://www.homebase.co.uk/sika-dustproofer-5l_p402670

I got these 3 above but I didn’t open them so I can return them if another better solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

Any surface coating will prevent dust. just apply the waterproofer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used epoxy paint with great success it will eliminate any dust and does a great job of sealing the concrete, just a note if you park a car you will want a high quality brand made for garages , I have seen where "indoor" epoxy was used and the area they parked the car the paint separated and pulled up from the heat of the tires.